# "Но вот" — запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, в очередной раз грамотно обосновать мою неграмотность.

Фраза: "Но вот ветер немного усилился".

В контексте: ветер сначала слабый, затем немного усиливается. Очень хочется поставить запятую после "Но вот"! Без неё, даже в контексте, читается с ошибочным смыслом - "ветер усиливается в отличие от...". Пауза в чтении должна идти после "Но вот...", а не после "Но вот ветер...". По правилам вроде бы запятая здесь не ставится никогда. Но без неё плохо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пауза в чтении должна идти после "Но вот...", а не после "Но вот
>   ветер...". По правилам вроде бы запятая здесь не ставится никогда. Но
>   без неё плохо.

Правила не могут объять все встречающиеся в языке случаи. Нужно обозначить *вводную* паузу после "но вот"  –  ставьте запятую. Возможна и постановка тире.

Из книг:

*Но вот, не утешил. <…> Но вот, не помиловал* (Д. Мережковский. Мессия).

*Но вот — все они расступились* (А. Грин. Обезьяна).

*Но вот, но вот – настал один из тех моментов, когда…* (Вирджиния Вулф. На маяк).

Comment: И даже многоточие. :) Поэтому и хочется обособить. Надеюсь, мне не станут тыкать этой запятой в глаза. Хотя... всё равно читать некому. :(

Answer (score 2):

"Но вот ветер немного усилился". Запятой после частицы ВОТ нет, потому что нет условий для её постановки. После "вот" запятая возможна только в таком случае: Ну вот, а я-то думал. Ну вот - междометное сочетание, выражающее разочарование на правах предложения со смыслом: ну вот что произошло, поэтому отделяется запятой. Насчёт паузы - это как кому хочется, я вот произношу с повышением тона и небольшой паузой как раз после подлежащего ВЕТЕР - это тема, а остальное с понижением тона - это рема. Всё вроде правильно.

Comment: Спасибо. Самое интересно, что в данном случае, что-то от междометия в этом случае есть. Эмоциональная окраска.  
"Еë спокойное дыхание смешивалось с шумом ветра, раскачивающего макушки сосен над крышей. 
Ветер будто бы подражал этому дыханию, накатываясь ровными волнами на крутой склон Иннслагфьель. И высокие сосны, будто в такт, склоняли свои зелëные головы перед пришельцем с запада. 
Но вот, ветер немного усилился. Задул более ровно и размеренно. И, слегка хлопнув входной дверью избушки, принялся завывать в трубе над очагом."

Comment: Не вижу и намека на междометие.  *Но вот впереди появились отборные защитники замка в малиновых накидках поверх камзолов, едва не зарубившие Главного кригсмана. [Василь Быков. Главный кригсман (2002)] *