# Верна ли постановка запятых и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

> Ему трудно бежать, но вот, он  наконец  что-то находит.

Comment: "В каком случае после “он” ставится запятая?". Неужели Вы ожидате, что на такой вопрос можно дать ответ?

Comment: Если вопрос о выделении запятыми слова *наконец*, то ответы можно найти здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%

Comment: и здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434824/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86

Comment: и здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc/2802#2802

Comment: А еще советую поискать слово *наконец* на этом сайте.

Comment: Нет, здесь речь скорее идет о сочетании "но вот". В вопросе ошибка (не после, а перед он), надо его отредактировать. Тема тоже разбиралась на форуме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427414/%D0%9D%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: @Jasmin. Очередной вопрос из игры "Угадайка".

Comment: Ну ошибся человек, отредактируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Jasmin, Вопрос может касаться как "но вот", так и "наконец". Я, пожалуй, сделаю его менее конкретным.

Answer (score 3):

**Ему трудно бежать, но вот, он наконец что-то находит.**

Авторская запятая обозначает паузу. Текст похож на репортаж, когда мы следим за героем, выполняющим какое-либо задание. После *** но вот*** делает пауза со значением "но вот, смотрите, обратите внимание, там что-то происходит".

В общем случае запятая не ставится, например:

**Но вот он наконец на что-то набрел**; впопыхах он не замечает, что находка его не только не имеет ничего схожего с мыслью...[М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин.  (1869)]

***Наконец*** здесь относится **к реальному действию**, является обстоятельством и не обособляется. Для сравнения: вводное слово ***наконец*** (1)завершает  перечисление чего-либо (тема оформления речи) или (2) выражает чувство досады.

Answer (score 0):

Для постановки первой запятой нет оснований. Если *наконец* означает *под конец*, то запятая не нужна. А если - выражает точку зрения говорящего или подчёркивает факт, имеет значение *все-таки*, то это вводное и запятая нужна.